# ReCAPTCHA verification is sending a SyntaxError

Tags: vue.js, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3, grecaptcha

So today I was trying to verify a CAPTCHA, and somehow is sending me an error (I'm sure I'm doing things okay).

This is the code I wrote to verify it (I'm doing this on the frontend just for education purposes with the CAPTCHA)

```js
try {
        const token = document.querySelector('#g-recaptcha-response').value;
        let url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=mysecretkey&response=token'
        fetch( url, {
          method: 'POST',
          mode: 'no-cors',
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data));
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
```

I printed in the console the URL so I can access it manually and check if everything is okay (It is okay).

And this is what I have in my contact.vue

```html
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LfC0kwcAAAAAMZZA0swdErB5_h8y6R_H7hZ85E7" data-size="normal"></div>
```

The error: `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input at eval` even inside a trycatch, and when I click on the link where the error is, it points to the line where I do `result => result.json()`

Any help with this? I'm using Nuxtjs

Answer (score 0):

You've got an extra `}` at the end of the code. After removing that, I'm not getting any other syntax errors on VS Code.

Plus, you may want to combine `let url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?'` and `url = url + 'secret=mysecretkey&response=' + token;` for brevity's sake.

Syntax errors mean it's a problem with what you wrote, not with how the program runs.

Fixing this and re-indenting your code, I end up with:

```js
try {
    const token = document.querySelector('#g-recaptcha-response').value;
    let url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=mysecretkey&response=' + token;
    console.log(url);
    fetch( url, {
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'no-cors',
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data));
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

Comment: Still getting the same SyntaxError